# Select xml node by its element contnt

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file like this one:

```
    <root>
       <sub>
          <name>Al</name>
          <code>001</code>
       </sub>
       <sub>
          <name>John</name>
          <code>002</code>
       </sub>
```

and a `List<string> lName= new List<string>(new string[] { "Jack", "John"});`

I want to edit "John" node, add "Jack" node and leave "Al" node as it is. What I did is:

```
System.Xml.XmlNodeList nodeNameList = FileXml.SelectNodes(@"//*[contains(name(),'name')]");
foreach (string name in lName)
{
   System.Xml.XmlNode nodeName=FileXml.SelectSingleNode("//root/sub/name");                 
   if (nodeName.InnerText == name)
   {
        //add
   }
   else
   {
        //edit              
   }
```

But it doesn't work. I thought that XmlNodeList works as a normal list but it doesn't. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can load your xml into the `Document` and then use `Descendants` with node name and then apply the `Where` filter on it with `Contins`. You can try something like this,

```
    XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(@"yourxmlpath.xml");
    var result = xmlDocument.Descendants("sub")
                .Where(x => lName.Contains(x.Element("name").Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: If you're going to pursue this solution, I'd advise just using an XDocument from the start and avoiding the whole XmlDocument API.  XDocument is easier to work with and will perform better in many scenarios.  However, if he has to use the XmlDocument API I'd avoid using LINQ to XML - if you've already loaded the document and the DOM for it, just stick with it.

Comment: Do you mean I can do this without using Linq? I would prefer to use only System.Xml since my whole code is based on it

Comment: `Xdocument` is in the same namespace. That is `System.xml.Linq` and it is using `linq`. And it is `XML-Linq` it will perform better (I think) and clean  and understandable code.

Comment: Yes I know, but in this way shouldn't I load the document 2 times?

Comment: Why the 2 times ? You can load once at start and perform all operations on that document.

Comment: Yes I can change my code if I don't have other options, still I have problem with ".Where", it says 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found

Comment: Can you post your tried code in above question. The code is tested at my end it works perfectly.

Comment: System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xmlDocument = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(sitePath);
foreach (string name in lName)
{
var result = xmlDocument.Descendants("sub")
                             .Where(x => lName.Contains(x.Element("name").Value)).ToList();
// if etc...

Comment: Why are you applying the foreach ? no need for foreach. And add the namespace  `using System.Xml.Linq;`

Comment: Did you add the using for these two `using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;`

Comment: Ok it works, thank you! Just one more question, now that I know if the name in my list is present, how can I select the correct node to edit it?

Comment: `result` contains the node llist with matching values  you can do whatever you want with that list.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple problems here.

First, you're comparing an XmlNode to a string with this code:

```
if (nodeName == name)
```

Which will never evaluate as true.  You want something like

```
if (nodeName.InnerText == name)
```

For your add logic, you'll need to create a new XmlNode and append it (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  For your update logic, just set the InnerText property on the node.

Comment: Yes sorry, actually I compare 2 string in that if(). I just cutted too much code!